# Parse: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, initialization

I am going through the Parse Quick Start tutorial for Javascript, and I downloaded the sample webpage and added my keys in, but the page shows me the error output and the Console shows:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)        https://api.parse.com/1/classes/TestObject
```

Anything I can do to fix this issue?

Comment: Suggests you used the wrong keys, but you give no details about the code

Answer (score 0):

I tried the program again today and no longer had this error even though I didn't change anything, so I did enter my keys correctly. Perhaps you just have to wait for some time before the keys generated by Parse will work.